# Как запустить функцию в другом .py файле

Tags: python

Я делаю GUI программу для запуска и взаимодействия с телеграмм ботом
Пытаюсь сделать так что бы можно было отправлять сообщения через программу от лица бота

Но для этого нужно как то запустить функцию из **GuiApp.py** в **bot.py**

Дополнение*

Нажатие кнопки в gui программе вызывает функцию send_button()

def send_button():
(Gui программа должна запустить функцию send_message(): в скрипте бота который уже запущен через subprocessPopen и размещён в той же папке что и gui)

(Вопрос скорее всего очень глупый и тд. Но я уже не знаю как это сделать)

Comment: Если gui на tkinter и бот асинхронный, то теоретически можно с помощью этого модуля попробовать совместить: https://github.com/insolor/async-tkinter-loop

Comment: GUI на PyQt5 а бот на aiogram  но спасибо за ответ, буду знать

Answer (score 1):

Не блокируйте главный поток, нужный для нормального функционирования GUI путём отлючения пулинга|хука бота, либо же запускайте прослушку апдейтов от телеграмма в другом потоке (последнее крайне не рекомендую).

Comment: А иначе никак? Просто мне это не только для бота пригодилось бы

Comment: @Nebula, иначе никак. Совмещать GUI и прослушку апдейтов тг для бота - ужасная идея. Для этих целей следует создать 2 отдельных скрипта. 1-ый - бот, 2-ой GUI, проинициализировать в последнем экземпляр бота без прослушки и отправять, когда нужно, сообщения.

Comment: GUI программа и является отдельным скриптом она запускает bot.py при помощи subprocessPopen

Comment: @Nebula, если всё так, как вы говорите, то ошибка в вашей реализации, т.к. при таком подходе и бот, и GUI должны работать исправно. Большего без вашего кода сказать нельзя. Возможно, вы ожидаете завершения процесса.

Comment: Я попробовал перефразировать вопрос

Comment: @Nebula, в GUI файле вы должны создать отдельный экземпляр бота для отправки сообщений, а не пытаться достать его инстанс из другого процесса, т.к. это попросту невозможно.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я надеялся что есть варианты))